# Take a thumbnail from a quicktime (movie) file

Tags: php, gd, thumbnails, quicktime, movie

Does someone know if it's even possible (in PHP) to take a frame/thumbnail from a quicktime movie on the server?

Something like the usual GD thumbnail generation, but for .mov files.

note: I'm using dreamhost, so I don't have more than web-panel access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dreamhost provides a [shared ffmpeg binary](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FFmpeg) in /usr/bin/ffmpeg, so you should definitely be able to call ffmpeg from php by using the system() or shell_exec() functions. The Dreamhost wiki has also an entry providing directions on how to install and configure ffmpeg-php..

Comment: +1 that's definitly a nice -- and satisfying -- answer ; good to know there are hosting providers that provide that kind of software!

Answer (score 4):

This looks promising: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/index.php

Comment: It does indeed look nice, but if he is on a shared hosting service and has no access to the machine (except a web-interface) and cannot install any PHP extension, it probably won't help him much :-(  (except as a way to indicate "get a real server for you only, on which you'll be root ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember having any way of doing that in pure-php :-(

Generally, the choosen solution is to call [ffmepg](http://ffmpeg.org/) in command-line, with stuff like [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec)

But, if you can't install software on your server, this will probably not be possible *(I doubt your hosting provider bundles ffmepg on their servers)*

There is even an extension to use ffmpeg from PHP without having to call it via command line : [ffmpeg-php](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/)

But, as it's a PHP extension *(and not just a bunch of PHP scripts)*, you'll have to install it on your server -- and we're probably back to the same problem :-(

Searching a bit, I found [AllBrand.nu Automagic Thumbnailer](http://allbrand.nu/thumbs/) ; they say (quoting) :

```
Features:

    * ...
    * Supports jpeg, gif, png, wbmp and video files
    * ...

Requirements:

    * PHP capable web server with GD support
    * ...
```

But it doesn't seem to be really known... So not sure it works well, nor that it's a good solution...

Anyaway... Good luck !

And if you find some working / nice solution, don't forget to let us know !

Comment: The thumbnail that the Allbrand.nu plugin creates for videos is an graphic with the filetype and filesize of the video. It is not an actual image from the video.